# Optimizing regular expression techniques

Tags: python, regex, parsing, optimization

**I am wondering about optimization techniques for regex**

So I am trying to parse every instance of money out of a 400k line corpus. I needed to also include lines such as `"$10,999.04"` as well as `"one billion and six hundred twenty five thousand dollars"` and everything in between. This required a very lengthy regular expression with multiple instances of groups like

```
MONEYEXPRESSION = '(?:\d\d?\d?(?:,?\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?)'
(one|two|...|ninety[\s-]?nine|hundred|a hundred|MONEYEXPRESSION)((\s*and\s*|\s*-\s*|\s*)(one|two|...|ninety[\s-]?nine|hundred|a hundred|MONEYEXPRESSION))*
```

Even more than that, In order to require it to be an instance of money and avoid matching lines such as `"five hundred people were at the event"` I have 4 OR'd options that require `"$", "dollars?", or "cents?"` to be in specific places in the sentence at least once.

**the regular expression is almost 20k characters! :(**

You can imagine with an expression this extensive, with any bad practices, it really adds to the time. I have been running this on the corpus for the past 2 hours and it has still not completed the matching. I was wondering what some of the best practices for optimizing and trimming unnecessary regex is. What operations I am using are expensive and can be supplemented for better ones. And if maybe there is just a better way to solve this problem?

Comment: Maybe you should write a real parser instead of trying to use a regexp for everything.

Comment: Believe me, I want to, but this is an assignment where I am required to use regex. Which is why I am not asking for a solution, but for techniques to make it run reasonably or minimize what I have already written

Comment: PCRE supports recursion, so instead of repeating the expression for numbers under 100, you can define it once and then refer to it before `hundred` and `thousand`.

Comment: Are you compiling the regex once upfront and then using the compiled version? Also, are you allowed to split it up into multiple regex pattetns so that you can test more frequent parts first and avoid testing every part on every line?

Comment: @ehaymore I am compiling once and I am allowed to split it into multiple patterns

Comment: Great. Find logical ways to split your overall expression into appropriate independent regexes. If you find that certain regexes are much more frequent than others, put their regex test first so you don't have to test the others. If the pattern distribution is such that this isn't helpful, then figure out which regexes take the most time (try each on some sample data) and put those last.

Comment: Do you have to use python? (i.e. perhaps you can find a faster regex engine.) Two suggestions: don't unnecessarily capture subgroups, so only use `(...)` when absolutely necessary; always prefer `(?:...)`. And compile your regex once and used the compiled regex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're asking about optimizing performance, so let's focus on that. What makes the regexp engine really slow is [backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html), and what causes backtracking is parts that *might* succeed in different places in the string, without clear ways to decide. So try these rules of thumb:

1. From the backtracking link above: "When nesting repetition operators, make absolutely sure that there is only one way to match the same match."
2. Avoid large optional components. Instead of something like `(<number>? <number>)? <number>` to match a sequence with space-separated elements, write `(<number> ?)+`.
3. Avoid components that can be satisfied by the empty string-- the engine will be trying to satisfy them at every position.
4. Ensure that unconstrained parts in your regexps are bounded in length, especially if the later part cannot be reliably recognized. Things like `A.*B?` are asking for trouble-- this can match *anything* that starts with `A`.
5. Don't use lookahead/lookbehind. Almost always there's a simpler way.

More generally, keep it simple. I'm not sure how you managed to get to 20K characters for this task, but I'll bet there are ways to simplify it. One consideration is that it's ok to match things that you will not see anyway.

For example, why match all numbers from one to ninety nine, and not just their components? Yeah, you'll match nonsense like "nine ninety and dollars", but that does no harm. **You are searching for money amounts, not validating input.**  E.g, this should match all written out dollar amounts less than a million dollars:

```
((one|two|three|...|twenty|thirty|...|ninety|hundred|thousand|and) ?)+ (dollars?|euros?)\b
```

Since this is tagged "python", here are two more suggestions:

1. If the task (or assignment) allows you to break up the search in steps, do so.
   A regexp that does everything often has to be so complex, that it is slower than simply running several searches in sequence.
2. Even if you are constrained to use one monster regexp, write it in pieces and use python to assemble it into one string. It won't make any difference when executing, but will be a lot easier to work with.

Answer (score 0):

I would try and do something of the sort:

```
keywords = ["$","dollar","dollars","cent","cents"]
my_file = r"c:\file.txt"
output = r"c:\output.txt"
filtered_lines = []
with open(my_file,"r") as f:
     for line in f:
         for k in keywords:
             if k in line:
                filtered_lines.append(line)
                break
with open(output,"w") as o:
    o.write("\n".join(filtered_lines))
```

Comment: Regex is required for this solution. Also, This is not line by line. I still need to be able to match "there are [one billion\ndollars] in my account"

Answer (score 0):

I'd keep the numerical and the written-out regex apart and do it in two steps, first extract the numerical amounts (which is the easy part) and then do the written-out amounts.

The most problematic thing with the written-out part is that if you have `one hundred people` it will try out all the billions and thousands and everything already on the word `one` just to find out in the end that there is no `dollars`. But even worse, it will try again everything for the word `hundred` and then for `people`...
Ideally it would therefore start from the back so it doesn't try to match everything with every single word but only 'dollars', 'cents' or whatsoever and only then do the expensive part.

Therefore, if possible, try to match your file back to front for the written-out stuff. It will definitely get quite hard to wrap your head around that but I bet it will be significantly faster.
And if it is not possible, I hope now you at least know where the main bottleneck is.

Ah, and some word boundaries might also help to reduce the matching from *at every character* to *at every start of a word*... I didn't mention it above but actually for this example the engine starts to match at 'o' then again at 'n','e',' ' and so on.